# Как получить содержимое тега с помощью Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Есть HTML страница в Selenium:

```
<span class="menu-title" style="color:#ff6613">
    <strong>34535.23</strong>
</span>
```

Нужно получить значение 34535.23

Пока сделал с помощью BeautifulSoup:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

И далее с помощью решулярных выражений. Как это реализовать, используя только Selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй следующее:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'google.com' # твой url
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='menu_title']//strong")
print(value)
```

`value` - значение которое нужно получить.

Answer (score 1):

Немного подредактировал ответ выше.
Поскольку надо подо получить текстовое значение в теге, то это надо явно указать.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://yandex.ru'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.text_black_yes")
print(value.text)
```

Т.к. если вывести просто value, то вы получите объект.